# MPNS Certificate Troubles

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mpns

i have troubles with MPNS certificates and secure notification channels.

First, I setup a channel without any servicename, the app is already in the store. Then I set up a MPNS certificate. We already bought a certificate with * in it, like "*.ourdomain.ext", so to safe many, we used that certificate as the MPNS certificate. Now i read, that certificates with a * cannot be used as MPNS certificates. But I cannot change the certificate during store deployment - always get an error that changing the MPNS certificate is now allowed.

The question is now, how do I fix this? We already bought a new certificate CN=mpns.oudomain.ext

How do i go from here? I need a solution that does not force the user to reinstall the app, since there is data that we only store on the client and not on the server.

Any hints on that?

PS: I also posted this question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/6eec4660-417d-42f3-8d12-ff6b0c1c9138/mpns-certificate-troubles?forum=wpdevelop).